# MYSQLi_Query not working with DB Connection in Includes Folder

Tags: php, mysqli

I've setup a dbconn.php file in the includes folder outside of the document root.  When I reference $mysqli from it as part of the select statement, I receive an error

```
Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli     
in /home/tgitcorp/public_html/Admin/admin_index.php on line 18
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given 
in /home/tgitcorp/public_html/Admin/admin_index.php on line 20
```

My dbconn.php is as follows:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','dbuser','pass','dbname');
    if ($mysqli->connect_error){
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli_connect_errno . ')'. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    $mysqli->close();   
?>
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
include_once '/home/tgitcorp/includes/dbconn.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML     
1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Tricorp Job Listing Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Job Listing Administration</h1>
    <h2>Step 1:  Please Select Your Restaurant</h2>
    <form id="frmSelStore" method="post">
    <?php 
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT location from restaurant');
    echo '<select name="ddlStore">';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . '"></option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to query the restaurant table to retrieve the location field and populate that field as values in my dropdown box.  Can anyone assist in resolving this error?

Thanks!

UPDATE #2:  Revised code block:

```
<?php 
$result=$mysqli->query($mysqli,'SELECT location from restaurant');
echo '<select name="ddlStore">';
while($row=$mysqli->query($result))
{
    echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . '">';
    '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

yields the error message:

```
Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given 
in /home/tgitcorp/public_html/Admin/admin_index.php on line 18
Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Empty query 
in /home/tgitcorp/public_html/Admin/admin_index.php on line 20
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($mysqli);` and after mysql_query, `var_dump($result);`

Comment: Did you include the `dbconn` file in the script you want to use. `include_once "path/to/dir/dbconn.php";`?

Comment: What's in your dbconn.php? Nothing in the code you've posted can generate the error you report.

Comment: added dbconn and full error message

Comment: You have an odd mix of OO and procedural style MySQLi calls though it is not a source of failure. You create a MySQLi object, but you use it in procedural style. Try `$result = mysqli->query('SELECT location from restaurant');`  And your fetch call: `$row = $mysqli->fetch_array($result)`

Comment: @Michael  when I change the syntax from mysqili_query to mysqli->query and mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli->fetch_array, I receive syntax errors in my IDE stating unexpected ->.

Comment: @SidC Sorry, should be `$result = $mysqli->query()` Note the `$`

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you close the connection as soon as you instantiate it? It must have something to do with that. Sounds to me that `$mysqli->close()` belongs inside the `if` block.

EDIT: In any case, closing the connection is optional, as described here: http://php.about.com/od/phpfunctions/qt/mysql_close.htm

Comment: Nice catch. That should be the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't go at the end of the script file below the `</html>` close.

Comment: @Michael, that's also a valid place. Yet, as far as I know, MySQL connections are automatically closed at the end of the PHP script.

Comment: @Joel  Thank you!!  My error message resolved.  Noobs like me need an extra set of eyes:)  Now I just need to populate the dropdown:)

Comment: @Joel Yes that's true, the connection should close at the end of the script. Wouldn't be a bad habit to close your connections manually either.